# Karate API DB Validation - match input SSN (111-22-3333) against stored DB string SS (111223333)

Tags: javascript, karate

In Karate,
I am sending the data with a SSN string (111-22-3333) in my API request, running a readValue query to fetch it and would like to match it with the stored DB value (111223333)

Is there a way I can transform the input request SSN to remove the dashes to MATCH the DB value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just JS:

```
* def before = '111-22-3333'
* def after = before.replaceAll('-', '')
* match after == '111223333'
```